Dropbox not auto updating on Linux
I'm using Dropbox on Ubuntu. I have an old laptop I don't turn on very often. I opened Dropbox and it shows this message:

You're using an old version of Dropbox. Please update to the latest version to continue using Dropbox.

Clicking the Update button just brings me to the Dropbox website to download the Dropbox package. But the package itself hasn't been updated for years. It's just some kind of install wrapper.

Just use DropBox in a browser -- there's no advantage to installing a separate app.


In the Update Dropbox dialogue click Exit Dropbox
Or if you've already dismissed the dialogue, click the Dropbox app icon > Quick Dropbox

Remove or rename ~/.dropbox-dist directory
ⓘ This folder only contains the Dropbox installation files, not any of the Dropbox configuration or any of your shared files, so it's safe to delete

Open Dropbox again and follow the installation instructions


